# Orient DB difference between load and fetching via select query

Tags: orientdb

I have noticed that when load with id is used the resulting object members(which are arrays of the other objects) are accessible via java. However when I fetch the same objects via a select query, only other members(which are not arrays of other objects) are visible.

Pl let me know how to access the arrays with a select query.

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: Can you add what queries you're running.

Comment: SELECT FROM PECustomerOrderHistoryEntity WHERE lastPredictionTime > 1522002600000  and lastPredictionTime < 1522318788000

Comment: Hi Ajay, which version of orientDB you use ?